# Use of the `spoiler` markup feature to visually hide images for the queasy?

Tags: discussion

One of the comments to the recent question, [Different colors of light are disrupting my focus. What lens feature minimizes this?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77620/11924), asked the OP for either a different example that doesn't include a large hairy spider, or at least a warning.

That got me to thinking, StackExchange has the `spoiler` markup functionality, whereby you surround what you want hidden with a modified blockquote, beginning the line(s) with `>!`, instead of just `>` as a normal blockquote.

What's the opinion / standard here for that? I don't think I've seen any posts in Photo.SE use the `spoiler` feature to obscure images, but it could potentially be useful for certain images or classes of images.

Forgot to mention: the `spoiler` feature also works on the iOS SE App (because you can't hover, you click the hidden area. A subsequent click will follow any links).

Below is they spider image would look like in the referenced question.

<sub>*Hover over the following image to see the **BIG HAIRY SPIDER***</sub>

> [image: jumping spider RGB focus breakdown]

Comment: (N.B. I'm voting down because I strongly disagree, following [meta voting conventions](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) — not against your having raised this.)

Comment: Aside: we do (relatively) often use the spoiler tag to hide NSFW images. See e.g. [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52556/how-to-achieve-this-effect-though-post-processing) and [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/who-is-the-photographer-of-this-black-and-white-photo-of-two-female-nudes-standi). (Both pages contain NSFW images, duh).

Comment: @mattdm Gotcha, I understand meta voting. Thanks for the note. =)

Comment: @PhilipKendall TIL. Well, that pretty much counters my NSFW-related answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh come on. It is a spider. I know people are scared of spiders to the point of irrational phobia, but masking every spider image on the internet is not the solution. If the question you referenced came with a spoiler tag, I would probably edit to remove it, since the existing animation is a clear illustration of the problem, and making people jump through extra hoops makes the question less clear.

If someone has debilitating fear of spiders such that they are triggered in an actually-damaging way by a photograph like that, they should be looking for professional help, not spoiler markup. (Or at least [try this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phobia-free/id627935349?mt=8).) If someone is just "queasy"... time to face the world.

Comment: Actually, I basically agree with the sentiment. Also, when I re-read the comment on the original question this refers to, I'm pretty sure I read it straight, but the commenter was probably being tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: And for the record, I mean "oh come on" in the general sense, not a personal one :)

Comment: =) I read it like you meant it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend the use of the `spoiler` markup with anything you would consider NSFW. It's very easy to accidentally move the cursor over a hidden image, revealing it to coworkers or oversensitive HR types.

The `spoiler` feature is implemented with straight CSS, meaning even if the reader didn't intend to view the image, and never hovered over the hidden area, it was loaded from the server by the browser. This will potentially show up in the reader's browsing history or corporate network traffic logs.